# Loop through spans inside of Leaflet marker

Tags: jquery, leaflet

Is there a way to loop through spans inside of a leaflet marker, using jQuery to replace the span inside the marker? Or what is the best way to go about looping through an array of data inside a marker in JavaScript?

I researched other methods on StackExchange, but nothing is working. The closest thing I have to anything working is using $els.slice...

```
        jQuery(function() {
            var $els = $('span[id^=KOJC_]'), i = 0, len = $els.length;
            $els.slice(1).hide();
            setInterval(function() {
                $els.eq(i).fadeOut(function() {
                    i = (i + 1) % len;
                    $els.eq(i).fadeIn();
                })
            }, 500)
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f00dl3/q1L5mrye/1/

Comment: Oke i will take a look

Comment: With which element do you want to replace the span?  Or do you want only change the span content?

Comment: I wish to replace the span - styling and text data in the span. A simple jQuery replaceWith didn't work, either, though.

Comment: okey.. Do you want to loop through the elements inside a marker or loop through all markers too ? I mean if you want to do this for one marker or for all markers ? Is it mandatory for you to use jQuery ?

Comment: Oke I will create an working FIDDLE to show how it's done

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to do this with jQuery. Just get all the icons on your map by their class, find their `<span>`([`jQuery.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)), remove them([`jQuery.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)) and add a new html element([`jQuery.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)):

```
for (div of $(".leaflet-marker-icon")) {
    $(div).find('span').remove()
    $(div).append('<p>25</p>')
};
```

Here is the working [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/q1L5mrye/3/).
In this example I have replaced all `<span>` of all markers with `<p>`

**UPDATE:**

If you want to replace the `<span>` of a specific marker with a specific `<span>` you could do:

```
// Replace the <span> of marker with ID '#KOJC_3' with the content of '#KOJC_1'    
var iconToReplace = $('#KOJC_3');   
iconToReplace.parent().append($('#KOJC_1'))
iconToReplace.remove()
```

Here goes the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/q1L5mrye/4/).

Comment: That doesn't work... I was wanting to loop through data values sort of animating the marker to show the past 6 hours of temperature data, so when all the markers show you can tell the speed air masses are moving. That js fiddle does nothing to be honest... it just shows 2 markers with 25 as the value. I'm wanting to loop through the KOJC_0, KOJC_1, etc... spans.

Comment: A fiddle should NOT be an final application if your needs, but rather an example how you could replace the span in each marker!" I wish to replace the span - styling and text data in the span. A simple jQuery replaceWith didn't work, either, though." <- That was your question. You said you want to raplace the span and i showd you how to replace the <span> inside each marker with <p>

Comment: Do you want to raplace the <span> element OR the text inside it ? Pls explain your question more accurate, that i can help you !

Comment: I want to replace the span element with the spans KOJC_1, KOJC2, etc... thats why I was using the $ele.slice(i) method. Sorry if I didn't clarify. I didn't put all the markers in because quite frankly the map I am generating has over 1000 markers I want to do this span "replacing" in

Comment: Okey lets take a new attempt :). Now i have replaced KOJC_3 with KOJC_1

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

This takes an array of elements and always animates the first array member (in other words, there's no counter to keep track of). During each step it simply cycles the array so that the next element is in front.

```js
$(function() {
    var els = $('span[id^=KOJC_]').hide().toArray();
    if (!els.length) return;

    $(els[0]).show();
    setInterval(function () {
        $(els[0]).hide();
        els.push(els.shift());
        $(els[0]).fadeIn();
    }, 500)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="KOJC_1">A</span>
<span id="KOJC_2">B</span>
<span id="KOJC_3">C</span>
<span id="KOJC_4">D</span>
<span id="KOJC_5">E</span>
```

For fun and profit we could extract that cycling behavior into a small jQuery plugin, like this:

```js
// plugin
$.fn.cycle = function (callback, interval) {
    var els = this.toArray();
    if (typeof callback === "function" && els.length >= 2) {
        setInterval(function () {
            callback(els[0], els[1]);
            els.push(els.shift());
        }, interval || 400);
    }
    return this;
};

// usage
$('span[id^=KOJC_]').cycle(function (curr, next) {
    $(curr).hide();
    $(next).fadeIn();
}, 500).hide().first().show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="KOJC_1">A</span>
<span id="KOJC_2">B</span>
<span id="KOJC_3">C</span>
<span id="KOJC_4">D</span>
<span id="KOJC_5">E</span>
```

Comment: Here's the thing - it works, but Leaflet renders the replaced span element outside of the map marker, off the map. A scrollbar will pop up and if I scroll below the map I will show my DIVs being cycled in and out.

Comment: Well then instead of showing and hiding their spans, try adding and removing the markers from the map via the Leaflet object. The same approach would work.

Comment: Another thing, please clean up your code. Here's a start. https://jsfiddle.net/q1L5mrye/7/. Since you have jQuery, use it to build and modify your HTML. Move fixed style to the CSS, there is no need for setting CSS that will never change via JS, or for inline CSS notations. Also get rid of all inline Javascript and move it to a separate .js file. Your JS code could be half the number of lines.